# Angular catchError firing unexpectedly when received StatusCode object from c#

Tags: c#, angular, post, api-design

I have an API call that is working on the C# backend, but the Angular front-end seems to take the C# reply as an error. Note the text of the object is 'comment added' indicating that a 200 OK response was sent back. Why is the catchError function triggering?

C# method:

```
[HttpPost("AddComments")]
public ActionResult<string> AddComment(BillingComments b)
{
    try
    {
        return StatusCode(200, "comment added");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "error adding comment");
    }
}
```

Angular method:

```
submitComment(newComment: BillingComments): any {
    return this.http.post('/api/BillingLg/AddComments', newComment)
        .pipe(catchError(this.appSvc.handleError<string>('submitComment', 'comment submitting err')));
}
```

Error returned by appSvc.handleError:

> Service error: submitComment failed
>   Msg: Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:49975/api/BillingLg/AddCommentsStatus: 200Detail: {"error":{},"text":"comment added"}Text: OK & return type specified (failed gracefully)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular by default parse the responses from APIs to Object, so by default, it expects JSON string to be returned from the API.

So you have two options, either to return a JSON instead of the string (Which is recommended), something like

```
return StatusCode(200, "{\"status\": \"comment added\"}");
```

Or you can make the HttpClient expects a string to be returned:

```
this.http.post('/api/BillingLg/AddComments', newComment, {responseType: 'text'})
    .pipe(catchError(this.appSvc.handleError<string>('submitComment', 'comment submitting err')));
```

Comment: Alternatively instead of structuring your response as json, you can use something like `return OkObjectResult("comment added")` and it will serialize and structure return objects as json automatically

Comment: I wound up using: `return StatusCode(200, Json("comment added"));` based on your explanation